# Build Android app in cordova with multiple page

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a project in ionic with Cordova. My project in `www` folder has three html file. How I can them attach together in my app. when I build my app just index.html build to apk file. How I can handle this?

Comment: you can just make a link to them. i.e from index.html you make a button to call page1.html

Comment: You need to include the 3 files in to index.html or 3 separate menu page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use framework such as ionic, jquery mobile and onsen ui.